# sms api not working in local machine but working if placed in the hosting server

Tags: php, mysql, api, sms

The below php code works well from a web server (i.e., where the sms server
is located) but not working well from a local machine with `xampp` or `wamp`.

The actual server is in godaddy

What am i missing out?

The code retrieves the connection details from a table which includes: 
username, password, msisdn, and sender. When the message is eventually sent, 
the message is flagged so that is is not sent again.

```
<?php

$id = 0;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","afrcan_wp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT id,message,username,password,MSISDN,sender,messagestatus FROM outgoingsms where messagestatus = 'not sent' LIMIT 1";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {

    $id=$row[0];    

    $text1=$row[1];

    $username=$row[2];

    $password=$row[3];

    $to=$row[4];

    $sender=$row[5];

    $messagestatus=$row[6];

 //$conn1=mysqli_connect("localhost","afrcan_wp","Sirhenry888","afrcan_wp");
$conn1 = new mysqli("localhost","root","","african_wp");
// Check connection
if ($conn1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE outgoingsms SET messagestatus='sent' WHERE id=$id";

if ($conn1->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn1->error;
}


$text = trim($text1);

$postUrl = "https://www.connectmedia.co.ke/user-board/?api";

$action="send";

$post = [
'action' => "$action",
'to' => array($to),
'username' => "$username",
'password' => "$password",
'sender' => "$sender",
'message' => urlencode("$text"),
];
$ch = curl_init($postUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "$response";

    //send messages
    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);

 $conn1->close();

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Is it an issue with the code?  internet connection?

Any assistance will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

if this works on a web server but doesn't work on your localhost , it maybe that CURL is having firewall issues . By default CURL uses the port 1080 . Check to see that that port is opn on your localhost or try changing the port by doing

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 8089);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line in your php configuration file (php.ini) after installing xampp server in your local machine or anywhere. It works perfectly.

curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"

Ensure that the CURL extension is installed and enabled in your PHP configuration. You can check your PHP configuration file (php.ini) and make sure that the following line is uncommented or added if it is missing:

extension=curl

The statement that CURL uses port 1080 by default is not accurate. CURL does not have a default port of 1080.

CURL is a library for making HTTP requests, and it does not have any inherent firewall or port-related settings. The port used by CURL depends on the URL being accessed, which is typically port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS, unless a custom port is specified in the URL.

Firewall issues or port restrictions can indeed affect CURL's ability to make requests, but it is not related to a default port of 1080. If you are experiencing issues with CURL not working on your localhost, it is unlikely to be related to a specific port. Instead, you may need to check other factors such as network connectivity, firewall settings, and PHP configurations to identify and resolve the issue.